# iOS navigationBar Setting transparent without effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
}
```

but navigationBar is still gray, Why?

In a new project this code is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed color using following code.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor =  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenPatter.png"]];

    CGRect bgFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds;

    bgFrame.origin.y -= 20.0;

    bgFrame.size.height += 20.0;

    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bgFrame];

    backgroundView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    backgroundView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenPatter.png"]];

    backgroundView.alpha = 0.6;

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:backgroundView];

 [self.navigationController.navigationBar sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

greenPatter.png is image of greencolor,
You can also replace

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor =  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenPatter.png"]];
```

to

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor =  [UIColor clearColor];
```

It's working for me.
Try and Let me know.

Comment: it's ok,but push next view controller animation have a some question..i think i can solve them

Comment: I think We have to paste on each view controller. I did this,
If you find another way Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I might state the obvious, but have you tried this?

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code do well.

```
UINavigationBar *bar =  [UINavigationBar appearance];
[bar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To set transparent I use this code

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Then to get color back

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {


    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];


    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in `AppDelegate.m` class

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topbar-bg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A fully transparent navigation bar:

```
- (void)transparentNavigationBar {

    UINavigationBar *navBarAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearance];

    [navBarAppearance setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [navBarAppearance setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
    [navBarAppearance setTranslucent:YES];

}
```

If you want to make it semi-transparent set translucent to NO and set desired batTintColor with alpha < 1.

Comment: without effect,bar color is gray

Comment: @sands.yu that's odd, it works for me in couple of apps.